# How to show(unfold) the hidden(folded) code in Intellij-IDEA with keyboard shortcut?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, pycharm, phpstorm, webstorm

How can I show(unfold) the hidden(folded) code in IntelliJ IDEA, as shown in the picture below, just using keyboard without touching the mouse?

[image: hidden code in intelliJ IDEA]

Answer (score 33):

In IntelliJ IDEA you can use to following shortcuts to fold/unfold code blocks:

- To *fold* and *unfold* **CURRENT** selected block of code:

  - <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> on Windows;
  - <kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> on Mac;
- To *fold* and *unfold* **ALL** blocks of code:

  - <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> on Windows
  - <kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> on Mac.

---

By the way, in **Settings → Editor → General → Code Folding** you can specify the default folding behavior for a various situations (e.g., *imports*, *one-line methods*, *inner classes*, *@SuppressWarnings annotations*, *array literals*, *generic constructors* and many others):

[image]

And even after that your folding/unfolding hotkeys listed above will work as well.

Answer (score 5):

To be sure which shortcuts are available go to settings > Keymap

then go to

Main Menu > Code > Folding

Expand 
  default on mac : cmd+
  default on win : ctrl + numpad +
Collapse default on mac : cmd-
  default on mac : cmd-
  default on win : ctrl + numpad -

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The only available option for your need (about import statements) is,

- Move your pointer to **(+)** button on the **left hand side of the statement** so you can see the pointer changes to hand mark.
  [image]
- Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>

Find [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/10.0/folding-and-expanding-code-blocks.html) for more info expanding/collapsing code. But this is more about blocks.

Answer (score 0):

### Easy to remember steps:

- Press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> twice
- Type `folding`
- Select `Folding` action
- All options related to `Expand` and `Collapse` should be visible now (with keymaps)