# Mark specific code block to fold/collapse by default in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, folding

I want to mark some particular functions to fold by default.
Something like:

```py
# PyFoldDefault
def my_func()  # PyFoldDefault - will hide a function.
    ...
```

Similar behavior there in PyCharm, for warnings suppression. PyCharm has a global logic like "fold all comments", imports, etc",  But I need more precise control during development.

P.S. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40967152/11277611) isn't duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do what you want is using [a code region](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20026966) and configuring it at `Settings` `>` `Editor` `>` `General` `>` `Code Folding` `>` `Collapse by default` and check `Costum folding regions`.

(You could also use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> shortcut on a code selection **but the folding won't persist after you restart the IDE** and it can't turn on/off folding at multiple places with a single action.)

```py
# region your_region
def my_func()
    ...
# endregion your_region
```

[image: screenshot of IDE settings dialogue]

---

This can't be done using single line comments, what your example in the question reminds of are the inspection warning [suppressing comments](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html#comments-ref) but no such single line comments exist to control code folding.

```py
# PyFoldDefault
def my_func()  # PyFoldDefault - will hide a function.
```